# Handling request exceptions while using threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am using request.post in thread as i have hit the url and not wait for response as i have around 4.5 k event to be sent one event at a time.

```
def request_task(url, data, headers):
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)

    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        print (e)
     except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
         print (e)

def fire_and_forget(url, json, headers):
    x=threading.Thread(target=request_task, args=(url, json, headers))
    x.start()

def push():
    fire_and_forget(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

I am not sure where should i be using try block and am i doing it the right way as i am using thread .

Could any one suggest how can i catch the exceptions also taking thread into consideration

Comment: Is there specific behavior you're looking for? As your code is now you already handle what happens when exceptions are raised.

Comment: @kingkupps i tried giving in a fake url but the exception was not handled . Which made me unsure if my code is handling exception at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while using request.post we can use

```
def request_task(url, data, headers):
try:
    r = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    print (e.response.text)
```

To catch the exception .